# How can I copy changes from one table to another, while avoiding an infinite loop, in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two databases, A, and B.  On database A, I have a table X, with 10 columns in it.  On database B, I have a table Y, with 7 columns in it.  4 of the columns from these tables match, and whenever one table updates one or more of these columns, I need the other table to update these columns.  How can I do this?  Replication wouldn't seem to work because the table structures are different, and insert/update triggers would seem to create infinite loops.

Comment: How come replication didn't help? If you just publish the 4 matching tables you should have no problem. Or do you want to update more than the 4 matching tables?

Comment: @Eton B.:  Sorry, I think I was unclear on that.  There are 2 tables, and 4 of the columns match on them, with unrelated columns on the side.  If it was just 4 tables that matched, replication would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the loops you could have your triggers not do an update if the values are equal?

Answer (score 2):

Replication works fine on tables with different structures, see [Filtering Published Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx).

As for triggers to avoid infinite loop, you would use context information to set up that you're currently in a 'replication' trigger so that you'd avoid looping, see [Using Session Context Information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252.aspx):

- in the trigger, you check if `CONTEXT_INFO()` says you're already in a trigger.

  - if YES, do nothing (return)
  - if NO, `SET CONTEXT INFO` to reflect your operation
- copy the data
- when the 'replica' trigger fires, will find your context info and do nothing
- clear context info
- return

Answer (score 0):

select * into NewTable from PastTable